# How to make Opencart type of category list, using own DB structure

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

My database structure as following

```
| id | parent_id | title | sort_order |
|  1 |         0 | Cars  |          0 |
|  2 |         1 | BMW   |          1 |
|  3 |         1 | Honda |          2 |
|  4 |         2 | X5    |          1 |
|  5 |         0 | Plane |          0 |
```

I need basic MySQL for this Table, to get Opencart type of category list as following

```
ID  Title
 1. Cars
 2. Cars -> BMW
 3. Cars -> BMW -> X5
 4. Cars -> Honda
 5. Plane
```

Answer (score 0):

The database structure you are referring to is also known as [Adjacency List Model](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). There is no way you could achieve the results you want with a single generic query. You have three variants:

1. use SQL stored procedures
2. fetch the whole table and [recursively process the results](http://salman-w.blogspot.bg/2012/08/php-adjacency-list-hierarchy-tree-traversal.html) with a server side language like PHP
3. hardcode the number of levels with union queries like this:

```sql
SELECT c.title 
FROM category AS c
WHERE parent_id = 0

UNION

SELECT CONCAT(c1.title, '->', c2.title) AS title
FROM category AS c1
LEFT JOIN category AS c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
WHERE c1.parent_id = 0 AND c2.title IS NOT NULL
UNION

SELECT CONCAT(c1.title, '->', c2.title, '->', c3.title) AS title
FROM category AS c1
LEFT JOIN category AS c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
LEFT JOIN category AS c3 ON c3.parent_id = c2.id
WHERE c1.parent_id = 0 AND c2.title IS NOT NULL AND c3.title IS NOT NULL
```